# PHP & MySQL totalrow counting with condition

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements, counting

I have a problem to get total rows counting with condition. This is my code

```
$pagesize = 10;
$recordstart = (int)$_GET['recordstart'];
$recordstart = (isset($_GET['recordstart'])) ? $recordstart : 0;

$town = $_GET['label_town'];
$sub = ucfirst($_GET['label_sub']);
```

Here is my selecting condition. I also use this condition to count totalrows

```
if (isset($_GET['label_town']) === true && isset($_GET['label_sub']) === true) {
$where = "WHERE p.label_town = '$town' AND p.label_sub = '$sub' AND `visible` = 1";
} else if (isset($_GET['label_town']) === true && isset($_GET['label_sub']) === false) {
$where = "WHERE p.label_town = '$town' AND `visible` = 1";
} else {
$where = "WHERE `visible` = 1";
}

// Selecting data 
$all_page_index = mysql_query("SELECT p.page_id, p.timestamp, p.label_town, p.label_sub, p.ime_nekretnine, p.mjesto, p.cijena_noc, p.krevet_apart, p.broj_apart, p.min_nocenja, p.description, p.visits, i.image_id, i.page_id, i.ext
FROM data_page AS p
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT MAX( image_id ) AS max, page_id
FROM images
GROUP BY page_id
) AS n ON p.page_id = n.page_id
LEFT JOIN images AS i ON i.image_id = n.max
$where
ORDER BY p.page_id DESC
LIMIT $recordstart, $pagesize");

// Counting rows with conditions
function totalrows() {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(p.page_id) FROM data_page AS p $where"), 0);
}
```

Selecting and displaying data works fine but problem is with SELECT COUNT. Always count totalrows no mater what condition is. Where I making wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass `$where` into `totalrows()` - it's out of scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `COUNT` is within function definition, where `$where` isn't defined. You need to pass it as a parameter or move query outside the function.